# Как скрыть div через this hide?

Tags: javascript

Как скрыть `div` через `this` `hide`? Как скрыть каждый `.notice` отдельно при клики `.notice_delete` ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.notification').on('click', '.notice_delete', function(){
        $(this,'.notice').hide();
    });
    $('.notice').on('click', '.notice_content', function(){
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.notice {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    background: #555;
    color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.notice_header {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    background: #555;
}
.notice_title {
    float: left;
}
.notice_delete {
    float: right;
    color: #999;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.notice_delete:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
.notice_act {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    background: #444;
}
.notice_content {
    width: 145px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notification">
  <div class="notice">
    <div class="notice_header">
      <div class="notice_title">Notice</div>
      <div class="notice_delete">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="notice_act">
      <div class="notice_content">
        Notice 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="notice">
    <div class="notice_header">
      <div class="notice_title">Notice</div>
      <div class="notice_delete">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="notice_act">
      <div class="notice_content">
        Notice 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="notice">
    <div class="notice_header">
      <div class="notice_title">Notice</div>
      <div class="notice_delete">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="notice_act">
      <div class="notice_content">
        Notice 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="notice">
    <div class="notice_header">
      <div class="notice_title">Notice</div>
      <div class="notice_delete">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="notice_act">
      <div class="notice_content">
        Notice 4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('.notice').hide();`

Comment: @Igor работает ответите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.closest` - ищет вверх по цепочке родительских элементов:

```
$(this).closest('.notice').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ниже ответ на вопрос "Как скрыть каждый .notice отдельно при клики .notice_delete ?".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.notification').on('click', '.notice_delete', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });
});
```